Do the anode and cathode of a lead acid battery switch in charging?

Here is the question I am trying to answer, with the basic knowledge that oxidation occurs at the anode both in an electrolytic and galvanic cell I see that B must be false which cannot be the answer in the first place.
When I looked up online I received conflicting results one article saying the opposite of the answer:

And multiple Indian sites with the same answer since this is a JEE PYQ, but there are times where a mistake in such question is duplicated across sites.

I feel like the stack exchange answer make intuitive sense but on the other hand the answer may be different due to some kind of convention specific to secondary cells.
(also tried chatGPT to no avail, it just agrees to which ever argument is provided last)

Please typed in your question. Do not post snap shot as part of or as your question.

Can you link the stackexchange answer?
